# Change "opacity" of ScrollPanel in GWT to "1"

Tags: gwt, datagrid, opacity

I'm using a datagrid with its default scrollPanel which set "opacity" to "0.7".

I want to change the opacity to "1" but the ScrollPanel is just created by some "div", not using "CSS" resources. 
So, I could not override any CSS resource also CSS attribute.

Please suggest me how to change the "opacity".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even though it its setting in some div element you can set the opacity in css... In your css type the following

```
.gwt-scrollpanel {
Opacity : 1.0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but scrollPanel of the DataGrid does not use gwt-scrollpanel. It is just two <div>, so I used "DOM.setElementAttribute" to update the Opacity and saw it takes effect.

Comment: "Rahul" (@user3829439) asks to @Xuna, "Can you elaborate on what you did. I am also facing the same problem."

Comment: I used DOM to get the correct element, then change opacity by Java code